# Is there CurrentValues.SetValues equivalent on SQLite?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Having problem on my Xamarin forms where I want to update specific fields only using model class.

```
       await validateToken.Update(new Auth
       {
           pid = defaultUser.pid,
           defaultUser = "N"
       });

        public async Task<int> Update(T entity) { 
            return await db.UpdateAsync(entity);
        }
```

But when I update using above code, it nulls all the fields that are not declared. In EF I just used `_context.Attach(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(UpdatedObj)` I'm not very sure on SQLite. Or can I just removed all the null properties when passing to Update?

Comment: generally when updating a row you start with a copy of the existing object, you do not use a new copy of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jason's comment. I came out to that idea where you need to get the whole old object and compare to the new object and put the new value. Below is my solution on my question.

```
public async Task<int> Update(Auth entity)
{
    Auth exist = await Get(entity.pid);
    var updateObj = (Auth)CheckUpdateObject(exist, entity);

    return await booking.Update(updateObj); 
}

public static object CheckUpdateObject(object originalObj, object updateObj)
{
    foreach (var property in updateObj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.GetValue(updateObj, null) == null)
        {
            property.SetValue(updateObj, originalObj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name)
            .GetValue(originalObj, null));
        }
    }
    return updateObj;
}
```

Comment: Glad you solved it. You could accept your answer which could help others with same questions. Here is some related doc [Store data in a local SQLite.NET database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows)